# Shown icon if old

Tags: icon

I have this code

```
<?php if( date('U') - get_the_time('U', $post->ID) < 24*60*60 ) : ?>New Post<?php endif; ?>
```

for posts that are under 24 hours old I want to alter the code for it to display Old Post if it's over 24 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just flip the "less than" `<` to "greater than" `>`:

```
<?php if ( date( 'U' ) - get_the_time( 'U', $post->ID ) > DAY_IN_SECONDS ) : ?>Old Post<?php endif ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Easier_Expression_of_Time_Constants

Comment: I added the code and it's not showing but the posts that have been made in 24 hrs work with the image

Comment: Can you post the code that's showing the image?

Comment: Never mind it was taking time to update